# How to divide up SQL SELECT results by percentages (pagination in server side)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am able to grab this first fifth but how do I get the other four fifths?

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT
...
```

Comment: Use `top 80 percent` with a descending `order by`.

Comment: But if I wanted to divide it up into five fifths?

Comment: Look at NTILE to divide into fifths (if you want to SELECT all the rows but just have a bucket column). There will be more efficient ways if you want to do 5 separate SELECT though

Comment: Five Selects is fine.  What would that be?

Comment: `NTILE(5) OVER (...` should get you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT ROWS` to select n number of rows after starting from nth row.

For example if ID is your order by column name and you have exactly 100 rows in the table then you can use below five queries. In first query OFFSET 0 Rows will indicate to select rows starting from first one. In second query select list will start from 21st row.     `FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY` will ensure that after starting row 20 rows (if available) will be selected in each query

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY


SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 40 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY


SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 60 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY


SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID
OFFSET 80 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve pagination using CTE. you have to give the starting row number and the ending row number to get the required number of rows.

```
DECLARE @StartingRow int, @EndingRow int
SET @StartingRow = 10 
SET @EndingRow = 20 
;with CTE as( 
   SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ID ) AS recordno  
   FROM Table 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE recordno BETWEEN @StartingRow AND @EndingRow
```